# React.js - Duplicating News Articles Issue and Warning: Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: reactjs, json, concatenation

In my news app I removed "next" and "previous" buttons on news page and instead added an InfiniteScroll to the app. in InfniteScroll the news keeps duplicating when i use "`articles: this.state.articles.concat(parsedData.articles)`" and warning for same keys shows up which is justified.
This code line was supposed to combine already existing news (12 articles in my case) to newly fetched articles from json file.

for newsbox component that has newsitems in it, the code is:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import { Component } from "react";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

export default class NewsBox extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    country: PropTypes.string,
    pageSize: PropTypes.number,
    category: PropTypes.string,
  };
  static defaultProps = {
    country: "us",
    pageSize: 12,
    category: "general",
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      loading: false,
      page: 1,
      totalResults: 0,
    };
    document.title = `SGR NEWS | ${this.props.category}`;
  }

  async updateNews() {
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=[SOME_API_KEY]&page=${this.state.page}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    this.setState({
      articles: parsedData.articles,
      totalResults: parsedData.totalResults,
      loading: false,
    });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.updateNews();
  }

  fetchMoreData = async () => {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=[SOME_API_KEY]&page=${this.state.page}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    this.setState({
      articles: this.state.articles.concat(parsedData.articles),
      totalResults: parsedData.totalResults,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="my-4 container">
        {this.props.category != "general" ? (
          <h1 className="text-center">{`Top ${this.props.category} news`}</h1>
        ) : (
          <h1 className="text-center">Top Headlines</h1>
        )}

        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={this.state.articles.length}
          next={this.fetchMoreData}
          hasMore={this.state.articles.length != this.state.totalResults}
          loader={<Spinner />}
        >
          <div className="my-4 ">
            <div className="row ">
              {this.state.articles.map((e) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    className=" n-box d-flex justify-content-evenly col-md-4 my-5"
                    key={e.url}
                  >
                    <NewsItem
                      title={e.title ? e.title : ""}
                      description={
                        e.title == "[Removed]"
                          ? (e.description = "")
                          : e.description
                          ? e.description.slice(0, 170)
                          : ""
                      }
                      imgUrl={e.urlToImage ? e.urlToImage : "/noImage.jpg"}
                      newsUrl={e.url}
                      date={
                        e.title == "[Removed]"
                          ? (e.publishedAt = "")
                          : e.publishedAt
                      }
                    />
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

for component news_item:

```
import { Component } from "react";

export default class NewsItem extends Component {
  render() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
    const { title, description, imgUrl, newsUrl, date } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem", height: "35rem" }}>
          <img src={imgUrl} className="card-img-top" alt="" />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{description}</p>
            <p className="card-text">
              <small className="text-muted">
                {new Date(date).toUTCString()}{" "}
              </small>
            </p>
            {title == "[Removed]" ? (
              ""
            ) : (
              <a
                href={newsUrl}
                className="link-success link-offset-2 link-underline-opacity-25 link-underline-opacity-100-hover"
              >
                Read More
              </a>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem exists in the fetchMoreData() and specifically in the concat line:

```
  fetchMoreData = async () => {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=[SOME_API_KEY]&page=${this.state.page}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    this.setState({
      articles: this.state.articles.concat(parsedData.articles),
      totalResults: parsedData.totalResults,
    });
  };
```

When i remove the line, no error shows up but as expected only 12 news articles appear.

Comment: just fyi, you leaked api key in the code section